# Showing Progress while Child row loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Coming again with another question :)

This time I had a requirement to show some progress while Child rows are being loaded. Since there is an Api call which relatively takes little time to return data, I do want to show the some progress unless the user who clicks the parent row is totally unaware whether there is a call done to see its child rows.

**What I have done:**

I wrote a style sheet class which has a

> loader-small.gif

image as this:

```
tr.loading td.details-control {
    background: url('/Images/loader-small.gif') no-repeat center center;
}
```

and applied like this:

```
$('#accountManagerEarningsDataTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {

        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row(tr);

        try {
            if (row.child.isShown()) {
                // This row is already open - close it
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('shown');
            }
            else {
                //Calling the loading Class ------>
                tr.addClass('loading');

                // Open this row
                var arrForTable1 = [];
                var arrForTable2 = [];

                totalBrokerage = 0;
                totalRetailBrokerage = 0;
                totalSelfServiceBrokerage = 0;

                console.log('You selected: ' + row.data().AccountManagerID);

                var settings = {
                    "columnDefs": [
                    { targets: 1, align: "right", decimals: 0 },
                    { targets: 2, align: "right", decimals: 0 },
                    { targets: 3, align: "right", decimals: 0 },
                    { targets: 4, align: "right", decimals: 2 },
                    { targets: 5, align: "right", decimals: 2 }
                    ]
                };

                //problems with asynchoronus call back
                var response = organization_GetAccountManagerDetailEarningsAccountData(row.data(), purl2, pcontext);

                if (response.success === "true") {
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.value.length; i++) {

                        for (var j = 0; j < response.value[i].Securities.length; j++) {

                            var itemRow2 = {};
                            itemRow2["Security ID"] = response.value[i].Securities[j].SecurityId;
                            itemRow2["Trades"] = response.value[i].Securities[j].Trades;
                            itemRow2["Buy Qty"] = response.value[i].Securities[j].BuyQuantity;
                            itemRow2["Sell Qty"] = response.value[i].Securities[j].SellQuantity;
                            itemRow2["Total Brkg"] = response.value[i].Securities[j].Effective_Brokerage;
                            itemRow2["Online Brkg"] = response.value[i].Securities[j].Online_Brokerage;
                            arrForTable2.push(itemRow2);

                            totalBrokerage = totalBrokerage + parseFloat(response.value[i].Securities[j].Effective_Brokerage);
                            totalSelfServiceBrokerage = totalSelfServiceBrokerage + parseFloat(response.value[i].Securities[j].Online_Brokerage);
                        }

                        totalBrokerage = Math.round(totalBrokerage * 100) / 100;
                        totalSelfServiceBrokerage = Math.round(totalSelfServiceBrokerage * 100) / 100;
                        totalRetailBrokerage = Math.round(totalRetailBrokerage * 100) / 100;



                        var itemRow1 = {};
                        itemRow1["Account ID"] = response.value[i].AccountId;
                        itemRow1["Account Name"] = response.value[i].AccountName;
                        itemRow1["..."] = '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">' + buildHtmlTable(arrForTable2, 'table2x' + j, settings) + '<p>Total Brokerage ' + numberWithCommas(totalBrokerage) + '</p></div>';
                        arrForTable1.push(itemRow1);
                        arrForTable2 = [];

                        totalBrokerage = 0;
                        totalRetailBrokerage = 0;
                        totalSelfServiceBrokerage = 0;

                    }

                    tr.removeClass('loading');
                    htmlTable1 = buildHtmlTable(arrForTable1, 'table1x' + i);
                    row.child(htmlTable1).show();
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                }
                else {
                    row.child('<table><tr><td>' + response.value[0].AccountId + '</td></tr></table>').show();
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                };
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }

    });
```

**The Problem:**

Firefox nicely shows the Progress image after the user clicks it, but Edge and Chrome does not show. Both browsers crossed this piece of code when I was debugging from developer tools of the respective browser.

Its browser compatible problem? Is there a solution for it? Help me please.

Comment: Does the progress bar is showing in chrome for a small duration, when the response from server comes back? There is an issue for chrome like that. If that is the problem there are fixes.

Comment: @Nitheesh It does not.

Comment: Please try the solution mentioned in the anser. I think it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of chrome there is such an issue while showing the loading bar while making a server call. Please make the following changes where you are making the service call. First add the class loading to the table

```
tr.addClass('loading');
```

After that make the service call by giving a timeout function

```
setTimeout(function(){
     var response = organization_GetAccountManagerDetailEarningsAccountData(row.data(), purl2, pcontext);
     ......
    //Your service calls and response call backs
},1);
```

On providing a timeout (say 1ms), Chrome will get the time to bind the loading bar to DOM, In other case the DOM Object is not available to show the spinner.

Comment: Awesome! At least the gif image is shown now, but it does not animate in google chrome; It remains static.

Comment: I think that's the issue of chrome. The same issue is also happening here.

Comment: Edge also shows the static *.gif image however firefox remains upbeat with everything working perfect. Thank You @Niteesh